# $2+2 = 5$? error in proof

Tags: arithmetic, radicals, fake-proofs

$$\begin{align} 2+2 &= 4 - \frac92 +\frac92\\
&= \sqrt{\left(4-\frac92\right)^2} +\frac92\\
&= \sqrt{16 -2\times4\times\frac92 +\left(\frac92\right)^2} + \frac92\\
&= \sqrt{16 -36 + \left(\frac92\right)^2} +\frac92\\
&= \sqrt {-20 +\left(\frac92\right)^2} + \frac92\\
&= \sqrt{25-45 +\left(\frac92\right)^2} +\frac92\\
&= \sqrt {5^2 -2\times5\times\frac92 + \left(\frac92\right) ^2} + \frac92\\
&= \sqrt {\left(5-\frac92\right)^2} +\frac92\\
&= 5 + \frac92 - \frac92 \\
&= 5\end{align}$$

Where did I go wrong

Comment: You're misusing the square-root function.

Comment: $4 - \frac{9}{2} < 0$.

Comment: $4 - 9/2 +9/2 \neq \sqrt(4-9/2)^2 +9/2$. Typically the misatke in these fake proofs is either division by zero or using $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ for negative/complex numbers.

Comment: The reason this "works" is that we don't intuitively see that $4<9/2$. You could do the same with $9/2$ replaced by $5$, and you'd immediately see the problem.

Comment: Since you have asked this question , I would redirect you to such dubious proofs (The case you have quoted is just the tip of iceberg) These are called as **MATHEMATICAL FALLACIES** .
These are interesting and understanding of these prevents us from being fooled . Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_fallacy
http://scimath.unl.edu/MIM/files/MATExamFiles/Weitzenkamp_A%20FINAL.pdf

Comment: This is so 1984-ish! - the book for those who don't know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Where did you go wrong, or where does the proof that you found go wrong?

Comment: How did $\sqrt{16 -2\times4\times\frac92 +(\frac92)^2}$ turn into $\left(\sqrt{16 -36 + (\frac92)^2}\right)^2$ (with that superscript $2$ OUTSIDE the parentheses)?

Comment: @HarishKayarohanam: Or just look at everything on M.SE with the "fake proofs" tag...

Comment: @MichaelHardy, it also disappears on the 8th step

Comment: Although $(5 - \frac{9}{2})^2 = (4 - \frac{9}{2})^2 = \frac{1}{4}$, it is not true that $5 - \frac{9}{2} = 4 - \frac{9}{2}$. [morbo]Square roots do not work that way.[/morbo]

Answer (score 53):

In the first line you have $4-4.5=\sqrt{(4-4.5)^2}$, which isn't true, because $-0.5\neq 0.5$.

Comment: I think $\sqrt{4}$ equals $\pm2$ and not just $+2$?

Comment: @Ramit No, it does not. It is actually a function.

Comment: No, $\sqrt{4}$ is positive, thats the definition of _the_ square root, opposed to "$2$ and $-2$ are square roots of four", which is true.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. Thanks.

Comment: @Tomas Then why do teachers everywhere assert that $\sqrt{x^2} = x$ and not $|x|$?

Comment: @ColeJohnson, because, sadly, those teachers are inadequately trained.

Comment: @Ramit $\sqrt{4}$ is the principal square root which *is* a function.

Answer (score 20):

Here's what your "proof" would look like correcting all the errors. As you can see, it's not nearly as impressive as a proof that 2+2=5.

$$\begin{align} 2+2 &= 4 - \frac92 +\frac92\\
&= -\sqrt{(4-\frac92)^2} +\frac92\\
&= -\sqrt{16 -2\times4\times\frac92 +(\frac92)^2} + \frac92\\
&= \left(-\sqrt{16 -36 + (\frac92)^2}\right) +\frac92\\
&= \left(-\sqrt {-20 +(\frac92)^2}\right) + \frac92\\
&= -\sqrt{25-45 +(\frac92)^2} +\frac92\\
&= -\sqrt {5^2 -2\times5\times\frac92 + (\frac92) ^2} + \frac92\\
&= -\sqrt {(5-\frac92)^2} +\frac92\\
&= -5 + \frac92 + \frac92 \\
&= -5+9\end{align}$$

For reference, the most serious mistake was in the 2nd line. In general, it's not true that $\sqrt{x^2} = x$, but rather $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$. For $x=4-\frac92<0$, you need to keep track of the extra minus sign coming from the absolute value. Other than that, there were some obvious typos that I've corrected.

Answer (score 7):

Basically, your proof is saying
$$
-0.5=\sqrt{(-0.5)^2}=\sqrt{0.5^2}=0.5
$$
Now find the error.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the other answers, even at the last,  $\sqrt{(5-\frac92)^2}=\pm(5-\frac92)$. with + it is wrong.

With $-(5-\frac92)$, that is $-5+\frac92$, adding the other $\frac92$ from the original equation, we do get $4$.

Comment: While this does work, $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$, the square root is usually taken to be a function, the **principal** square root.

Comment: This is incorrect. $\sqrt{x} \ne \pm x$. This works because that -ve sign is missing from the start which you are adding in the end with this fallacy.

Answer (score 3):

$\sqrt{\left(4 - \frac 9 2 \right)^2} = 4 - \frac 9 2 = -0.5.$

It's not true.

If $a \geq 0$, then $\sqrt{a} \geq 0$.

Comment: You're repeating what has already been said. I wouldn't write $a\geq 0\implies \sqrt a\geq 0$. The "real" square-root is defined only for positive entries, so one should just say $\sqrt a \geq 0$ for any $a$.

Answer (score 3):

How did $\sqrt{16 -2\times4\times\frac92 +(\frac92)^2}$ turn into $\left(\sqrt{16 -36 + (\frac92)^2}\right)^2$?

Then later, you seem to assume that since $\left(4-\frac92\right)^2$ is the same as $\left(5-\frac92\right)^2$, it follows that $4-\frac92=5-\frac92$.  Like saying that since $3^2=(-3)^2$, it follows that $3=-3$.  A well known mistake.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{a^2}=|a|\not=a$$
Watch the signs.

Answer (score 1):

In the very first line, you assumed that $a=|a|=\sqrt{a^2}.$ But this is not true in general. In particular, it is false for negative $a.$ And in fact, $$4-\frac92<0,$$ so in this case we do not have that $$4-\frac92=\sqrt{\left(4-\frac92\right)^2}=\left|4-\frac92\right|$$ as assumed.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, $\sqrt{(4-\frac{9}{2})^2}$ is what? Well, $4-\frac{9}{2}$ is $-\frac{1}{2}$. But we all know $(-\frac{1}{2})^2$ is $\frac{1}{4}$ since $(-x)^2=x^2$. That means that $\sqrt{(4-\frac{9}{2})^2}$ is $\frac{1}{2}$. So the assumption that $\sqrt{(4-\frac{9}{2})^2} = 4 - \frac{9}{2}$ leads to $-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$ which is clearly wrong.

So the square root of a positive number squared is a positive number and the square root of a negative positive number squared is also a positive number. So if we assume $\sqrt{(-x)^2} = -x$ to $x = -x$ which is false.  Note: *x* is positive, not negative. This is the correct statement:

$\sqrt{(-x)^2} = \sqrt{x^2} = x \not= -x$