# mean of two consecutive number helps proving both number equals..

Tags: arithmetic, radicals, fake-proofs

Well I was wondering how is this possible.

let say:

## **4=4**

## -> R.H.S

$=4-(9/2)+(9/2)$

$=\sqrt{ (4 - ( 9/2 )) ^ 2}+ (9/2)$

$=\sqrt{ 16 - 36 +( 9/2 )^2}+ (9/2)$

$=\sqrt{ - 20 +( 9/2 )^2}+ (9/2)$

$=\sqrt{ -45 + 25 +( 9/2 )^2}+ (9/2)$

$=\sqrt{ 5^2 - 2x(9/2)x5 +( 9/2 )^2 }+ (9/2)$

$=\sqrt{ (5 - (9/2))^2 }+ (9/2)$

$=5- (9/2) + (9/2)$

## =5

going through this I found that every number can be proven equal to any number??????
still scratching my head.....

Comment: I had faced this problem about 15 years ago :). I assured myself saying that in the penultimate step you should take 9/2-5 instead of 5-9/2.

Comment: See also: [$2+2 = 5$? error in proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457490/22-5-error-in-proof)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is old.

$$x \ne \sqrt{x^2} = |x|$$

for $x < 0$.

Comment: @@vedran can you elaborate please....

Comment: $4 - 9/2 = -1/2 \ne 1/2 = \sqrt{(4 - 9/2)^2}$, so your second line is wrong.

Comment: The mistake is going from the first line to the second. $4 - \frac 92 \ne \sqrt{\left(4 - \frac 92\right)^2}$.